# Not able to set the path to files correctly in android.gradle

Tags: android, regex, gradle, groovy, filepath

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    mybuildpath('path.name').string.split(" ")
            .collect {
        mybuildpath('[' + it + ']pkg.lib').string
    }
    .findAll {
        it.length() > 0
    }
    .each {
        from(new File(it)) {

            if (!getCurrentFlavor().contains('SomeKeyWord')) {
                include '**/folder1/**/*.so'
                include '**/folder2/**/*.so'
                //                include '**/lib1.so'
                //                include '**/lib2.so'
                //                include '**/lib3.so'
                //                include '**/lib4.so'
            } else {
                include '**/*.so'
            }
        }
        into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs-folder')
    }
}
```

This in android.gradle of my project I have to include few .so files during compile time. 
folder1 and folder2 have all those libraries [lib1,lib2,... etc], I want to include them all.
but this code is not working and it's not importing any library in my native-lib-folder, 
But when I comment those 2 lines and uncomment the below 4 [those specific **/lib1.so , ..  so on ,, ] those 4 libraries are getting copied in native-lib-folder.
I have searched and I feel that regular expression syntax is correct but still can't understand what I am doing wrong.
Please guide

Answer (score 1):

Ii is [Ant path style](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) not regex.

Try

```
include '/folder1/*.so'
include '/folder2/*.so'
```

instead.